# Proof of Limit Properties

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a} {\left[ {f\left( x \right)} \right]^n} = {\left[ {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a} f\left( x \right)} \right]^n},\,\,\,\,{\mbox{where }}n{\mbox{ is any real number}}$$

I have seen a proof where $n$ is an integer.

Many textbooks just state that it is also true for any real numbers. I wonder what would the proof for real numbers look like?

Comment: Show the result for rationals; invoke continuity.

Comment: I believe this is true if you can prove that the limit of composition is the composition of limits, as $f(x)^n=\exp(n\ln (f(x)))$

Comment: Let $g(x)=x^n$ then you need $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(f(x))=g\left(\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)\right)$ -- it's the continuity of $g(x)$ itself I believe. Rewritten: $\lim\limits_{f\to b} g(f)=g\left(b\right)$.

Comment: @benjamin How are you defining exponentiation for which the exponent is any real number?  That is to ask, "what is the value of $x^y$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $x\ge 0$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$?"  Once you have a definition of this, you can proceed to show that $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)^y)=(\lim_{x\to a}f(x))^y$